# Installing ejabberd on windows

Tags: windows, ejabberd

Hey, I am trying to install ejabberd on a local machine,runs windows-vista (that as the first step in developing a web chat application; then I would go dabble with jaxl library and jquery/strophe for the chat application).

I downloaded ejabberd windows installer from [here](http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads/). I run(double click) the installer, it opens a empty window, that is all. I looked into the services(in task manager, in control panel), i see nothing in the sorts of its name. Any idea what could be wrong or how to know if it is installed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

On windows 7, make sure you run the setup file as an administrator.

Answer (score 2):

Go to start, run, and type cmd to open a command prompt.

CD to your ejabberd\bin folder. Mine in “D:\Program Files (x86)\ejabberd-2.1.9\bin”.

Then run the following command:

```
ejabberdctl status
```

You should see something like this “The node ejabberd@localhost is started with status: started ejabberd 2.1.9 is running in that node”

Comment: I got this in stutus: The node ejabberd@localhost is starting with status: started ejabberd is not running in that node

Comment: What may the reason for this ?

Comment: Any error if you run ejabberdctl start?